# If $H$ is a $p$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $G$ is a $p$..

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $H$ is a $p$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $G$ is a $p$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that's contained in $H$, show that $G = H$

I know that a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is any set $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that has the following three properties:

1. zero vector $\in H$.
2. For each $u \in H$ and each scalar $c$, vector $cu \in H$.
3. For each $u$ and $v \in H$, sum of $(u+v) \in H$.

I also know that the dimension of a nonzero subspace $H$ is the number of vectors in any basis for $H$

Finally, I know that **The Basis Theorem** states:

$H$ be a $p$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Any linearly independent set of exactly $p$ elements $\in H$ is automatically a basis for $H$. Any set of $p$ elements $\in H$ that spans $H$ is automatically a basis for $H$

But I'm unsure of how to exactly get started proving that $G = H$

Comment: Blanking your question after it has already been answered is not appropriate. I've rolled it back to the original version.

Comment: @T.Bongers Was an accident.

Comment: The time that was an accident, was it the first, second or third blanking of the question?

Comment: Was an accident. @T.Bongers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G$ is $p$-dimensional, it has a basis consisting of $p$ linearly independent vectors. Since $G$ is contained in $H$, these vectors belong to $H$. Since they are linearly independent and $H$ is $p$-dimensional, they form a basis for $H$. Thus $G$ and $H$ both have these $p$ vectors as a basis and so they must be equal.

Comment: The problem states that $G$ is contained in $H$. This means that $G \subseteq H$ or in other words, for any $x \in G$, we also have $x \in H$.

Comment: I think that your last sentence needs a little more explanation to complete the proof. ;) A skeptical person should ask that why the last sentence is true. :)